# pyodbc certificate verify failed

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pyodbc

I need to connect with pyodbc to a mssql server and receive following error:

> ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:EE certificate key too weak] (-1) (SQLDriverConnect)')

My connection string is as following:

```
    try:
        conn_str = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={self._server};DATABASE={self._database};UID={self._username};PWD={self._password}'
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        return cursor
    except pyodbc.Error as err:
        print('pyodbc error')
        print(str(err))
```

How to avoid the check of the ssl certificate?

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert on the server? Don't forget, [ODBC 18 encrypts by default](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228)

Comment: There is no cert at all, that's why I want to disable the check.

Comment: *"There is no cert at all"* So it's the default self-signed cert. If you don't want to use SSL then you need to disable it in your connection string.

Comment: "you need to disable it in your connection string" exactly, but how?

Comment: Did you have a check of the prior link?

Answer (score 0):

In the connection string add:

> Encrypt=no;

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and struggled to find a good answer. There's a lot of confusion out there around ODBC. If you're on Linux, I would recommend checking to see if there's PDF documentation that comes with the `unixODBC` driver. It can be found where the driver is installed (in our case, we were messing with Data Bricks, so `/opt/simba/spark`).

In that documentation, it says you should use the argument `AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1`. This worked for us.